# Javascript validation error

Tags: javascript, validation

I am new in javascript and I have been stumped by this problem.

I have been through a lot of the prior posts and perhaps missed the answer but my question is a bit different, I have a form which I need to validate the user's input entries, most of the entries are numbers in the same range, another is % so it must be between 1 and 100 (the formula divides it by 100 so the user does not put in a decimal.

Actually between 1 and 10 (10% is the max)

My html for one of the inputs is:

```
<input style="" name="size" id="size" class="inp" value="25000" onblur="sqftvalidate();">
```

(If I need to post the entire page or table, please let me know)

the function is:

```
 <script>

 /*   Test function with size  input line 499  */

function sqftvalidate(x)
{
   if(isNaN(x)||x<1000||x>100000)
   {
       alert("Value good ");          // to test if validation is working 

       //docalculation();  this is the function to call if the validation is good 
       return true;
  }
  else
  {
       alert("Value must be between 1,000 and 1,000,000");
       return false;
  }
}
</script>  

<!--   validate input functions  end    -->
```

Comment: Try with `onblur="sqftvalidate(this.value);"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is also wrong + you should also pass parameter to function - sqftvalidate(this.value)... Otherwise you don't know what value of x is (undefined)...

```
if(isNaN(x)||x<1000||x>100000)
 {
     alert("Value must be between 1,000 and 1,000,000"); 
  }
  else //or you could write (!isNaN(x) && x>=1000 && x<=100000)
 {
     alert("Ok...");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition, it is totally opposite of what you need.

So simply replace code inside if with the code inside else statement.